# Why setTabLabelVisibility is not found in 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

Tags: android, android-tablayout, material-components-android, material-components

I can find the api "setTabLabelVisibility" for TabLayout, but not from the official release of 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'. Why?

The 1.0.0 release should include that as stated here.
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/48a07e1df9d89a17044c8d24762513c0360ca172

Why the 1.0.0 release is marked at the commit of 1.0.0-rc01?
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases

Answer (score 0):

setTabLabelVisibility might not have made the cut for 1.0.0 -- that code was cut several months ago.

'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha01' should now be available, and it should contain setTabLabelVisibility.

Answer (score 0):

The method [`setTabLabelVisibility`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout.Tab.html#setTabLabelVisibility(int)) is not in `TabLayout` but in **`TabLayout.Tab`**.

Just use something like:

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setTabLabelVisibility(TabLayout.TAB_LABEL_VISIBILITY_UNLABELED);
tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setTabLabelVisibility(TabLayout..TAB_LABEL_VISIBILITY_LABELED);
```